# Getting the week of month in android

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following code:

```
c = Calendar.getInstance();

wno = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

as its feb 2015 and first day is sunday. Its showing week number as 2 when date is set to 2nd feb 2015.

I also tried

```
c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);    
wno = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

but still showing 2

I want it to show 1. How can I make it to count from monday?

New code:

```
    Locale locale;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (locale != null) {
            newConfig.locale = locale;
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        fileid = settings.getInt("class", R.raw.se1e);

        if (settings.getBoolean("darkui", false)) {
            setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();

        locale = Locale.GERMAN;
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

still not showing proper number. what should I do?

Comment: It ***is*** counting from monday. At sunday, the week ends, so if the 1st of february is a sunday, the 2nd (which is monday) is part of the second week...

Comment: I want it to show "1st week" when the week has the first monday of month

Comment: You might want to start from sunday then. If the week starts from sunday, this will be the first week of the month

Comment: c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY ); still no luck it is still showing week no as 2

Comment: Try with *Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);* -- this Locale has Monday as first day of week.

Comment: Hey, your code giving me the correct output, it is showing me 1 : Just check import java.util.Calendar; and `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  int wno= c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
  Log.e("MainActivity", "wno is =====" + wno);`  This outputs 1

Comment: @AADTechnical I copy-pasted your code. still showing 2

Comment: Is date correctly set on device or emulator where you are testing this code

Comment: yes. On my PC using normal java it shows 1 but when I run it on my phone shows 2

Answer (score -1):

Kindly try below solution, to get the current week.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int week = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: Not only are you answering a 7 year old question, you almost literally have the same code as mentioned in the question